# Bash command to rename files and convert datestamp from 'dd[st/nd/rd/th] mmm yyyy' to 'yyyymmdd'?

Tags: shell-script, date

Is there a simple bash command that will match the date string in a filename like this...
`File Name 20th May 2019 descr.txt` (File Name and descr are strings of variable length)
...and convert it to a filename like this:
`File_Name_20190520_descr.txt` 
?

I know there are some other questions that discuss date-based filename conversions but they are either related to Perl or don't specifically mention the ordinal indicator (1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th).

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh`:

```
zmodload zsh/datetime
autoload zmv
zmv -n '(* )(<1-31>)??( ??? <1900-2100>)( *.txt)' \
  '${1// /_}$(strftime %Y%m%d "$(strftime -r "%d %b %Y" $2$3)")${4// /_}'
```

Remove the `-n` when happy.

That's if the month is the 3 character abbreviation. If it's the full name:

```
zmodload zsh/datetime
zmodload zsh/langinfo
autoload zmv
zmv -n '(* )(<1-31>)?? ('${(vj:|:)langinfo[(I)MON_*]}')( <1900-2100>)( *.txt)' \
  '${1// /_}$(strftime %Y%m%d "$(strftime -r "%d %B %Y" $2$3$4)")${5// /_}'
```

Those assume the file names are in the language of the current locale. If the month names are always in English, you can set `LC_ALL=C`. In any case, where te language is not English, you can't necessarily expect the abbreviations to always be 3 characters long or the `th`, `nd`, `rd` to be two characters long, so you'd probably need to adapt.

Answer (score 0):

awk:

```
{
    # split by date
    split($0, a, /[0-9]{1,2}[a-z]{2} +(January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December) +[0-9]{4}/, seps)
    # remove trailing nth from day
    sub(/[a-z]{2}/, "", seps[1])
    # get desired date format from shell command
    "date -d '" seps[1] "' +%Y%m%d" | getline d
    # replace space with _
    gsub(/ +/, "_", a[1])
    gsub(/ +/, "_", a[2])
    print a[1] d a[2]
}
```

Read comment as explanation.

I use full name of month, you might need to change it to abbreviation.